# Replacing Heroku Domain with Godaddy

Tags: heroku, dns

I want my sample RoR heroku app pointed to a custom domain.
Several tutorials said in takes up to 72 hours but 5 days had passed and still I cannot see my app on my custom domain.

What I did: 
 
1. I bought a domain in Godaddy.
2. I worked on on my Heroku Settings:

> === calm-cliffs-51233 Heroku Domain
>   calm-cliffs-51233.herokuapp.com 
>   === calm-cliffs-51233 Custom Domains
>   Domain Name       DNS Target
>   ────────────────  ──────────────────────────────
>   www.budgetan.com  www.budgetan.com.herokudns.com

3. In Godaddy, I tried to change IP address in the A record etc.. but Finally I just deleted everything and left these three:

> Type   Name    Value   TTL Actions 
>   CNAME   www budgetan.com.herokudns.com  1 Hour  Edit
>   NS  @   ns47.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour  
>   NS  @   ns48.domaincontrol.com  1 Hour

4. Then I waited.
5. 5 days later I still get this error in Google Chrome:

   > This site can’t be reached 
   >   www.budgetan.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
   >   Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
   >   DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: It works for me: `➜  ~ dig www.budgetan.com +short
budgetan.com.herokudns.com.`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @SimoneCarletti. I looked up what dig is and found "Verify your DNS settings by running dig www.yourdomainname.com cname +short. If it returns www.yourdomainname.com.herokudns.com then you have set it up correctly." I am not seeing "www" but it did show budgetan.com.herokudns.com, so I am assuming I have set that up correctly. Now I am looking at the angle of SSL setup maybe something is wrong there.

Comment: just want to update that I have corrected my problem by commenting out 'config.force_ssl = true' as a heroku representative described that my site was redirecting to an https. I haven't purchased any certificate yet. Thank you for the help!